# How do i pass a function from remix loader function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, remix.run

I am trying to send a function as one of the value from a remix route loader function

```
export const loader: LoaderFunction = async ({ request }) => {
  const userId = await requireUserId(request)
  const user = await getUserById(userId)

  const canUserPerformAction = getUserPermissions(user)

  const organisations = await Organisation.find({}).exec()
  return {
      organisations,
      canUserPerformAction
  }
}
```

getUserPermissions(user) returns a function with the current user context, which needs to be used in the frontend.

this function always ends up being undefined when I fetch it using useLoaderData() in the default component/ frontend. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loader can either be called during the whole page generation, or using an XHR when navigating in your app.

Your loader have to return a valid Response object, which will usually be a JSON response : https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/api/conventions#returning-response-instances

In your code sample, the returned object is automatically converted to a JSON string, and since functions aren't valid json, it gets stripped.

You will need to call your `canUserPerformAction` and return its actual result as JSON.